# Unable to retrieve entries created with Channel Form

Tags: safecracker

I'm allowing users to create entries from the front end using Channel Form.

I can see those entries in the Control Panel. However they are not appearing when I try and retrieve the entries using the standard {exp:channel:entries} tag.

Anyone experienced that before? Any ideas why its happening?

Comment: Did you verify that the status of the new entries matches the status that the channel:entries tag is pulling? (by default, "Open" only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem turned out to be something with my Playa data not being saved. Once I had fixed that issue the entries created with Channel Form starting appearing in my templates. I guess the relationship was being lost which was causing the query to fail. Relieved to have it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing from what Jeremy said, you need to make sure that the channel that they are posting to has a status group assigned to it.

After you're sure that they do have a status group,

go to Admin -> Channel Administration -> Channel Form

and choose the default status for the channel.

If you have any statuses other than "open" and "closed" you may need to add the "status" attribute to the entries loop

```
e.g.
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" status="open|pending"}
    <!-- Content -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The code example above should show everything in the news channel, with a status of "open" or "pending".

Hope this answered your question.

Comment: Hi Shadydragon, I made sure that the channel had a status group assigned. I then checked in Admin > Channel Form, my channel was set to Default so I assigned it "closed". I then created a new entry again via a Channel Form and it shows in the control panel but it won't show in my exp:channel:entries tag. My parameter looks like this:  status="open|closed|Disapproved". I can list entries created directly in the CP but not via Channel Form.

Comment: I took a look at the database and everything looks ok. Here is my channel entries tag: {exp:channel:entries 
        channel="logbook" 
        status="open|closed|Disapproved"
        author_id="CURRENT_USER"
        orderby="date"
        sort="desc"
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    }

    <p>{entry_id}</p>

{/exp:channel:entries}